# How to arrange courses to timetable?

Tags: university, time-management

I would like to ask if there is some algorithm how to arrange courses to timetable. I study at the university and we can choose a few different lesson times for each subject.

The problem is how to coordinate all subjects with student's requirements, for example to have school only 2 days a week and/or to select some hours based on capacity.

One subject - you have to select one from the first table and one from the second table (it's lecture and seminar). There can be only one table to select from (only seminar/only lecture):

[image]

---

[image: Course timetable]

Comment: Would something like Prolog (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog) help solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks. My problem is that I don't have time to learn Prolog:) I was looking for some idea how to arrange it. But I understand that's not so simple.

Comment: Check out [this stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2162397/168775) for a related discussion. Not sure if it'll help you at all, but you'll learn something.

Comment: Are you asking as a student (because you need to fill your own schedule), or as an administrator (because you want to add a feature to your registration site)?

Comment: As a student. I want to have some variants precomputed based on my preferences (school only on Tue and Thu) and then select the best variant for me.

Comment: As Tom brought up in his answer, this is an algorithm question. It seems more appropriate for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 5):

Why did this get moved to https://academia.stackexchange.com/ ?  This is an algorithm question!

Anyway, it so happens some friends of mine have one of the top timetabling algorithms, based on competition wins.  Here is a link to the paper (which will include references to other state-of-the-art timetabling algorithms)

> An automatically configured modular algorithm for post enrollment
>   course timetabling Chris Fawcett, Holger H. Hoos, and Marco
>   Chiarandini - Technical Report TR-2009-15, University of British
>   Columbia, Department of Computer Science, 2009. [[pdf]](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/cgi-bin/tr/2009/TR-2009-15.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

There are algorithms for timetabling, but I doubt that you would want to get into the level of detail required for understanding them and applying them to your - as I take it - one off situation. Timetabling is a difficult problem for a computer to solve when there are many activities and people to timetable. It is an NP-hard problem, and a hot topic of current computer science research.

Perhaps something like [this](http://www.timetableonline.com/) would help you? I haven't tried it so I can't comment on whether it is a useful/competent solution.